# Resize root partition in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning, root

I am using Ubuntu 16.04. I have posted a screenshot of my partitions below. My root partition `/dev/sda1` is almost full, and my `/home` partition `/dev/sda3` has plenty of unused space. Is there a way that I can use some space from `/dev/sda3` to increase the size of my root partition `/dev/sda1` ?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: that is a lot of space used for root. perhaps you should look at clean up. Try `sudo apt-get clean` and `sudo apt-get autoremove` and removing old unused kernels.

Comment: @ravery: Not really if you installed many packages or have a bunch of stuff in `/var`, e. g. web pages or data bases.

Comment: @DavidFoerster -- if that is the case, it would be mounting a partition to /var would be an easier fix.

Answer (score 0):

You need to boot using a live CD/USB to make changes on the root partition. Then you can use Gparted ...